# How to change an element in for-of loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, ecmascript-6

How to I change the object in the array with For-of loop?
Following code:

```
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

for (let v of arr) {
    if (v === 'c')  {
      v = 'f';
      break;
    }       
}

console.log(arr);
```

I want to find the first letter c and change it to an f, but arr doesn't get changed, probably because it is not referenced ? But shouldn't the v of arr make that the object v is the same as the one in arr ?

Comment: No, JavaScript doesn't allow aliasing of properties. The variable `v` is a *copy* of the value in the array.

Comment: To do what you want, you could use `.map()`, or use `.findIndex()` to find the target element's index and then modify the array.

Comment: for in loop over an array is a bad idea. Use built in Array methods to loop over the array!

Comment: @epascarello coffee time :)

Comment: @Pointy Ah, read that as in not of. lol Still see of as a bad choice when you have forEach/filter/map/etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript does not create references to simple values such `String`. To get array referrenced, you need to let array be an array of objects like `[{char : 'a'}, {char : 'b'}, ...]`. Then in your iterator you can change elements of array through changing of the `char` property

```
let arr = [{char: 'a'}, {char :'b'}, ...];

for (let v of arr) {
    if (v.char === 'c')  {
      v.char = 'f';
      break;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Ok, understand. What if the array does not contain Strings, but a Custom object with properties? Can I then just change the whole object like v = newObject ?  or do I have to v.myProp = newObject.myProp?

Comment: @williamwmy I don't sure, but I think that only `v.myProp = newObject.myProp` possible

Comment: @williamwmy Technically `v` contains just a reference to array element, so `v = newObj` will place to `v` a new reference, and old reference to array element will be destroyed

Comment: thanks, I tried, and you are right, I cant just set the whole object, and since the object has tons of properties, I have to loop through them too which makes the code a bit messy.

Comment: @williamwmy, you can place to array `[{obj : yourObjectWithTonsOfProperties}]` and then `v.obj = newObj`

Answer (score 6):

`v` is not a reference to the array element, it's just a variable that is assigned the value that the array iterator yields. If you assign to it, only the variable `v` changes but not the array.

To do that, you need to explicitly reference the property with its index and assign to it:

```
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
for (let [i, v] of arr.entries()) {
    if (v === 'c')  {
      arr[i] = 'f';
      break;
    }       
}
console.log(arr); // ['a', 'b', 'f', 'd', 'e']
```

An iterator does not provide a way to mutate the underlying structure, you need to do it yourself.

Comment: It logs: `[
  "a",
  "b",
  "c",
  "d",
  "e"
]`. Why?

Comment: @rv7 I had mixed up index and value from `.entries()`. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 2):

As detailed in the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) spec, `let` is declaring a new variable from a copy of your array element. So changing the `v` will not change the value in the array. This is shared by `var` and `const` and is simply just javascripts behaviour. When you create a new object, it starts empty.

Your loop is basically saying "For every element in `arr`, declare a variable holding a copy of it and then if that variable is `c`, change that copy to `f`"

Comment: The behavior has nothing to do with `let`. You would see the same with `var`.

Comment: I never said Let was the problem, but that it's behaviour would cause what is happening

Comment: But the same can be said about `var` or `const`. The behavior is by no means specific to `let`, it's simply how values work in JS in general.

Comment: Thats true and a fair point and, although I never said it was specific, I'll take your advice and mention that it isn't `let` specifically causing the problem

Answer (score 1):

Before you change `v` both, the array and `v` point to - or in this case have - the same value:

```
arr[2] -> 'c' <- v
```

After you change `v` it has a different value, but you didn't change the array:

```
arr[2] -> 'c'  v -> 'f'
```

`v` and `arr[2]` are only placeholders, but different ones.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer:

```
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

let i = 0;
for (let v of arr) {
  if (v == 'c')  {
    arr[i] = 'f';
    break;
  }
  i++;
}
console.log(arr);
```

:-P